# Remove non-selected dynamic jQuery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

**Short info:**
I'm working on a chatsystem based on websockets. For the design I'm using jQuery UI tabs. These will be used to chat in different chatrooms and private chats. The tabs are dynamicly created when opening a new room or private chat. The idea is that users are able to close them as well.

**The problem:**
I'm perfectly capable to create the tabs dynamicly. But the problem arises when a user wants to close them again. Somehow I need the close button to send the correct tab index towards the tab remove function. If the user has the tab currently selected, it's quite easy to get the index. But if the user closes a tab while a different one is selected, not so much. So how can I solve this problem?

**Code I've got so far (simplified):**

```
var tabs;
var tabCounter = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
    var ul = tabs.find("#tabs-ul");

    $("<li><a href='#newTab'>New Tab</a><a href='#' onclick=\"closeTab('"+id+"')\"><img class='imgCenter' src='layout/images/system/tabClose.png'></a></li>").appendTo(ul);
    $("<div id='newTab'>Name :<input type='text'></input></div>" ).appendTo(tabs);
    tabs.tabs("refresh");
});

function closeTabs(id){
    var getID = tabs.tabs('option', 'active');
    tabs.tabs("remove", getID);
}
```

As you can see, I've already got it working in case the tab is selected. I've prepared the `closeTabs()` function with an id parameter so that instead of trying to find the index when the tab will be closed, it's already there when creating it. I just don't know how to do it?

**Additional problem:**
I'm suspecting the indexes will change when you remove one of them. If that happens, my idea like this will run into some serious trouble. Is it possible to prevent the indexes from changing? Or do I have to use a whole different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After figuring out that `tabs("remove", id)` is deprecated, I've solved my problem quite easily. First I've added a data attribute to the tab list:

```
<li data-user='uniqueID'>...</li>
```

Next I've simply changed my `closeTabs()` function into:

```
function closeTab(id){
    $("li[data-user='" + id + "']").remove();
    $("#"+id).remove();
    tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
}
```

Problem solved. Works like a charm!